# How can I merge two objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, background, mask

In Illustrator how can I merge this roof vector to the background of the square?

[image]

[roof and square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7hOS.png)

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand what you want the end result to be. Could you include an illustration (perhaps done with Photoshop) of what the finished product should look like?

Comment: I have the feeling that a clipping mask is what you desire. Do you want it to look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ToGRl.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bart Arondson has pointed out, what you want to use is a clipping mask.

This is how it works:

You need to group your roof-tiles first. Select all of them with the *black selection arrow*, and use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or go to `Object -> Group`.

Then you make sure your square is on top of the roof-tiles group. Pretend this multicoloured pattern is your roof.

Select both roof and box and go to `Object -> Clipping mask -> make`:

[image]

That should give you this result:

[image]